# No sound through Turtle Beach Z300 USB headset

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound

Running Ubuntu 14.04, clean install with updates.  My headset is a Turtle Beach Z300.

I've read plenty of solutions for no sound in Ubuntu but nothing has worked yet.  Here's what I've done:

- My device shows up under **System Settings > Sound**
- I selected both *Digital Output (S/PDIF) Turtle Beach Z300* and *Analog Output Turtle Beach Z300* and tried *Test Sound* -- can't hear anything
- I commented out `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` from `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- I installed `pavucontrol` and ensured that the Z300 was set as fallback and not muted
- The headset works fine under Windows on another hard drive

Any suggestions?  I want to move my desktop back to Linux as the primary OS and working sound is a must.

Comment: Have u used pairing via Bluetooth? Have you got Turtle Beach Z300 option in Sound Settings? If u got that means make that to default. I suggest Bluetooth will do help. This may help you http://cdn-assets.turtlebeach.com/products/369/z300_user_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a hardware issue.  I had the headset plugged into a USB 3 port.  Switching to USB 2 worked fine.